# Why is text and inline contents not evenly distributed in columns?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have paragraphs with inline-block elements in multiple columns design and the contents is not distributed evenly, the code is something like this:

```
<style>
.col { column-count: 2; }
</style>

<div class="col">
<p> ...Some text... <img src="with-some-height">
<p> ...Egestas magna Some longer text...
</div>
```

In [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/yjh53oe7/) at width 1600px I would expect the text *Egestas magna* in the second column to use the space evenly. When I remove the `<p>` tags, the result is better, but still not optimal. I use Opera 62 if that matters.

Please explain how the space is calculated and if there is a CSS way to make the columns more even. I need two columns design with unknown height.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/zw43j7vd/4/

Comment: Uable to replicate - https://jsfiddle.net/zaeg3dcu/

Comment: @Paulie_D With your fiddle, I see a clear difference between FF and Chrome. FF has a much better distribution of the content among the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty `div` with `height: 250px` in there which is creating a lot of empty space in the first column. Also you didn't close your `p` tags.

If your fix all that it works as desired: https://jsfiddle.net/jp7uvty2/

(Note that i added `.col > p:first-of-type { margin-top: 0;}` in that fiddle to avoid the default space above the first paragraph, which otherwise results in different top margins in the first and second column.)

Comment: The div simulates an image in text. The text distributes decently, but big inline-block elements (like the div) in the text mess it. I expect the columns to be similar height even when they contain inline-block elements. The closing p tags [is not required in HTML5](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-p-element)

Comment: "I expect the columns to be similar height even when they contain inline-block elements." - How should that work? Inline and inline-block elements are still bound to their position inside other elements, and that's where they appear in the content if they don't have `position:absolute`.

Comment: These elements increase the total height of the inline contents. I expect the column wrap in the contents in a place where the difference of columns height is minimal. In the example right column is much shorter, it would be better if the column wrap was right after the inline-block element.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure the exact way you wish the columns to be spaced because your explanation is a bit bare, but I would suggest using ```flex`` properties to make it responsive.

`justify-content`
`align-items`

flex and grid are your best bet to space containers evenly with unknown dimensions.

Comment: I can not use flex layout for this. I want a continuous text (with inline-block elements like images) to distribute evenly in two columns without messing the contents with div tags like "this is the first half and this is the second".

Comment: this is still possible with flex/grid.... what exactly do you mean by "div tags like 'this is the first half this is the second' "

Comment: The browser should place the soft column wrap at a place where the height of columns are similar, so sometimes (screen resize, dynamic contents added etc.) part of the contents may move (overflow) from the first column to the second (or back). I can't imagine how to achieve this by flex.